# I ran my project and got a "Could not compile settings" error

Tags: flutter, gradle, settings

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO KA7 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\sekek\BusSystem\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\sekek\BusSystem\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  settings file 'C:\Users\sekek\BusSystem\android\settings.gradle': 3: expecting EOF, found 'LICENSE' @ line 3, column 14.
     found in the LICENSE file.
                  ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        26.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Here is my settings.gradle file.** This is my first time encountering an error like this so I don't really know how I am going to go about it.

```
//Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
//Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
//found in the LICENSE file.

include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"

}
```